# Apache serving different index files accordingly to domain requested

Tags: apache

I have two index files located in the same directory like so:

```
/var/www/site/index1.html
/var/www/site/index2.html
```

Those are basically two different localisations of the same html.
Files share same .css and .js files so I want to keep them in the same directory.

I want to make apache serve files accordingly to the domain requested:

```
www.domain1.com  -->  index1.html
www.domain2.com  -->  index2.html
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: You either define different `DirectoryIndex` documents in the two host configurations inside your http server or you implement a rewriting rule for each requested host name ("domains") (you need a `RewriteCond` _and_ a `RewriteRule` for that). You will find good examples for both in the documentation of the apache http server.

Comment: @arkascha thank you! I already have two .conf files for each site. For the index I tried `DirectoryIndex` but unfortunately from the documentation I didn't get how to bind `DirectoryIndex` to different requested domains... As I understand there should be only one `mod_dir` file where I specify `DirectoryIndex`. If I create two, how apache would know which instructions to use? Or could I also specify domains in `mod_dir` somehow?

Comment: @arkascha I got it thank you! That wasn't the separate file

Comment: Things like `mod_dir` are _modules_ , so software packages you can load into the http server software. So you enhance the capabilities of the server software. The configuration of an apache http server is (typically) oriented on virtual hosts, one per host name ("domain name") typically.

Comment: I got it, for some reason I thought that `mod_dir` is a one more configuration file, other than `.conf`. Thank you for help!